# TCMalloc - get size of allocation for a pointer

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, free, tcmalloc

Using TCMalloc - given heap allocated object, is there any way to get the allocated size of the object (meaning only the size passed in malloc call)?
I'm asking for a "reliable" method (i.e, not going a word size back assuming the allocation size is stored before the pointer)

Comment: Why do you need this? There is no such thing forn the standard `malloc` either?

Comment: @Michael Walz - I don't think it is important why I need this. Also, TCMalloc is much more comprehensive library than standard malloc, and it has also heap profiling tool, etc...

Comment: The "why" is often important (See this: http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Michael Walz - allocation counting for requests, when each request exclusively owns a group of threads. Each request is inspected once in a while to see if it satisfies memory constraints. 
The Idea is to Proxy the existing malloc/free calls with a minimal management of a counter per request. When malloc is called the size is trivially known, but not when free is called

Comment: You could write your own `mymalloc/myfree` functions that call the original `malloc/free` or `TCMalloc/free` or what ever, and store the allocated size before the actual data. But this adds a little overhead.

Comment: @Michael Walz I'm trying to avoid any overhead in management. Your idea is a well-known approach, however, it can cause serious fragmentations (and performance degradations) if calling malloc of multiple of  page size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.6, TCMalloc [includes](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/src/gperftools/tcmalloc.h.in#L118):

```
size_t tc_malloc_size(void*);
```

which returns the usable size of the allocation starting at the argument.

It is identical to the glibc `malloc_usable_size` (or BSD's `malloc_size`), and `libtcmalloc` includes aliases for both of those functions.

However, it is *not* necessarily the originally requested size. It may be larger (and usually is). I don't believe that TCMalloc (or most other malloc implementations) retain that metadata, so there is (afaik) neither a reliable nor an unreliable mechanism to time travel back to the original malloc call and inspect the request size.

Comment: I tried it, with calling malloc_usable_size, and it seems to have alias to tc_malloc_size (I cannot call directly to tc_XX api since the library is preloaded).